# VBA: Error 91 ("Object Variable or with Block variable not set")

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying things from Excel to PowerPoint and it works most of the time. Except sometimes I get an error ("Object Variable or with Block variable not set") in this one workbook.

Below you find the part of my code where the error occurs; I only included `MainSub`for completeness' sake, the actual relevant part is in `SubCapAnl`. More specifically, the debugger stops at the line `Debug.Print "wb: " & wbCapAnl.Name`, which I included to get to the root of the error. So something seems to be up with the workbook, but again, usually the code works.

Also, `Set wbCapAnl = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PathCapAnl, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)` works every time. It opens the workbook without fail, so I don't get what the issue is. I tried using `DoEvents` after opening the workbook, but no luck. Every other workbook I open in my code - and there are a lot of them - works fine.

```
    Dim CapAnlExists As Boolean
    Sub MainSub()
        Dim CapAnlArray As Variant
        PathCapAnl As String

        CapAnlExists = True
        CapAnlArray = Array("C01", "C02", "25", "35", "45", "46", "49", "51", "52", "53", "54")

        If Dir("C:\CapAnl " & YearNum & " " & MonthNum & ".xlsm") = "" Then
            MsgBox "CapAnl " & YearNum & " " & MonthNum & ".xlsm couldn't be found."
            CapAnlExists = False
        Else
            PathCapAnl = "C:\CapAnl " & YearNum & " " & MonthNum & ".xlsm"
        End If

        If CapAnlExists Then
            Call SubCapAnl(CapAnlArray)
        End If
    End Sub



    Sub SubCapAnl(CapAnlArray As Variant)
        Dim wbCapAnl As Workbook
        Dim wsCapAnl As Worksheet
        Dim CapAnlSheet As Variant
        Dim lRowKA As Long
        Dim rngKA As Range

        Set wbCapAnl = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PathCapAnl, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)


        For Each CapAnlSheet In CapAnlArray
            Debug.Print "wb: " & wbCapAnl.Name

            If CapAnlSheet = "C01" Or CapAnlSheet = "35" Then
                lRowKA = wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Cells(wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
            Else
                lRowKA = wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Cells(wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            End If

            If CapAnlSheet = "C01" Or CapAnlSheet = "C02" Then
                Set rngKA = wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Range("B2:M" & lRowKA)
            Else
                Set rngKA = wbCapAnl.Sheets(CapAnlSheet).Range("B2:P" & lRowKA)
            End If

            rngKA.Copy
            Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count, 12)

            DoEvents
            mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoCTrue
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
                .Height = 432
                .Top = 45
                .Left = 30
            End With


        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next CapAnlSheet

        wbCapAnl.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

Comment: This looks somehow strange. What would happen if you write `wbCapAnl.Save` after the `Set wbCapAnl = Workbooks.Open(...` Would the errors still appear?

Comment: I think I found the issue. When you run the check on the path directory you fail to set the `CapAnlExists` to true, as such when you are creating the workbook object you are specifying an empty string, thus, the object is empty and hence you're getting your error. Try pasting an explicit string in the `FileName` and check your results. I could be wrong.

Comment: Additionally, you shouldn't be able to call the sub based on your code above, so not sure if this is an accurate representation of your actual code. You need `CapAnlExists` to be set to true to call the `Sub SubCapAnl()`. The default state of a boolean is `False`. So maybe an edit required? Run an `If Not wbCapAnl Is Nothing` test after you set the object to verify if I am correct.

Comment: @Dean Yeah, sorry, I messed up and forgot to copy the `CapAnlExists = True` . I edited it.

Comment: @Alex Where do you get the error if you run the `Debug.Print` before the `For` loop and after you set the object? As I think there could be a problem with the `CapAnlArray` but need to be sure with the test.

Comment: @Dean It's the `Debug.Print`. I initially thought the same as you, that something was wrong with the array (I tried it with less elements etc, all to no avail). However, then I tried `Debug.Print "wb: " & wbCapAnl.Name` and got the same error. So something is up with the workbook, not just the sheets or the names of the sheets.

Comment: @Alex I have run a test on my side, but I used `Filename:="Book2.xlsx"` and it works fine. So there is something wrong with your workbook object `wbCapAnl` and how you're setting it. Sorry I can't be of more help I'm afraid.

Comment: @Alex in your original code are you declaring the `PathCapAnl` as a `Public`? Above you're not passing `PathCapAnl` the string through to the `SubCapAnl()`. Hence it's an empty string as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Dean Yeah, it's public. Thanks for your help! I'm just gonna have to run some more tests, maybe at some point I figure out what's wrong.

Comment: "I messed up and forgot to copy the CapAnlExists = True . I edited it." As well  `PathCapAnl As String` without Dim?  Do not patch up the code in the question. Put in code as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example